# Extracting an array of integers from a string, using java-streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm having a hard time understanding why this code returns an Object[] and not an int[] ("line" is a string I read off a file that looks like "1 2 3 4 5").

```
Arrays.stream(line.split(" ")).map(Integer::valueOf).collect(toList()).toArray()
```

I hope you can help me understand, thank you !

Answer (score 2):

The stream is of type `Object`, use `mapToInt` to convert as `int`:

```
Arrays.stream(line.split(" ")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray()
```

Comment: `Pattern.compile(" ").splitAsStream(line).mapToInt(...` avoids the temporary array, fwiw.

Comment: @Shawn but this only pays of for a rather large number of substrings, as otherwise, `String.split` is significantly faster than the regex engine when the pattern consists of a single ordinary character.